# how can we define a global method?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to IOS Development and I'm unable to figure out how we can define a global method.
I have a function
func getBanners(){} declared in a class.
I want to declare and use it globally.

Comment: Methods cannot be defined globally but functions can.

Comment: Globals are usually a Bad Smell. Explain what you're _really_ trying to accomplish and perhaps we can suggest a better way.

Answer (score 1):

you have several options here you could add it on global scope or introduce a class/enum with a static func. I personally would go with the enum, if functionality has to be available in another module, you have to set the access control to public.

Cheers
Sir SwiftAlot ✌️

```
// on global scope
func getBanners() -> [Banners] {
    return []
}

// class static func
class Banners {
   static func get() -> [Banners] {
       return []
   }
}

// enum with static func
enum Banners {
    static func get() -> [Banner] {
        return []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function defined in a class

```
class Foo
{
    func bar() { ... }
}
```

provided you have an instance of the class, you can call it anywhere in the module:

```
Foo()->bar()
```

Note that `Foo()` creates an instance of `Foo` and then `bar` is called on that instance.

If you want to be able to call the function without an instance, you need to mark it static:

```
class Foo
{
    static func bar() { ... }
}
```

To call it you need to specify the class:

```
Foo.bar()
```

Note that you can no longer access instance variables because the function is associated with the class itself, not a specific instance of the class.

Also, it doesn't need to be a class. You can also have static functions in `enum`s and `struct`s

You can also have a bare function not declared in a class:

```
func bar() { ... }
```

Call it like this

```
bar()
```

The above is not generally considered good practice, although there are occasions where it is used in the Standard library e.g. `print()` and `zip()`

To complicate things further, there are keywords to control the visibility of where you can call the function from

```
private func alpha() { ... } // Visible only in the current source file
internal func beta() { ... } // Visible only in the current module
func gamma() { ... }         // default visibility is internal so visible in the current module
public func delta() { ... } // visible anywhere in your program
```